# How can I create a String from UTF8 in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, utf-8

We know we can print each character in UTF8 code units?
Then, if we have code units of these characters, how can we create a String with them?

Answer (score 20):

With Swift 5, you can choose one of the following ways in order to convert a collection of UTF-8 code units into a string.

---

### #1. Using `String`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2922828-init) initializer

If you have a `String.UTF8View` instance (i.e. a collection of UTF-8 code units) and want to convert it to a string, you can use `init(_:)` initializer. `init(_:)` has the following declaration:

```
init(_ utf8: String.UTF8View)
```

> Creates a string corresponding to the given sequence of UTF-8 code units.

The Playground sample code below shows how to use `init(_:)`:

```
let string = "Café "
let utf8View: String.UTF8View = string.utf8

let newString = String(utf8View)
print(newString) // prints: Café
```

---

### #2. Using `Swift`'s [`init(decoding:as:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2907004-init) initializer

`init(decoding:as:)` creates a string from the given Unicode code units collection in the specified encoding:

```
let string = "Café "
let codeUnits: [Unicode.UTF8.CodeUnit] = Array(string.utf8)

let newString = String(decoding: codeUnits, as: UTF8.self)
print(newString) // prints: Café
```

Note that `init(decoding:as:)` also works with `String.UTF8View` parameter:

```
let string = "Café "
let utf8View: String.UTF8View = string.utf8

let newString = String(decoding: utf8View, as: UTF8.self)
print(newString) // prints: Café
```

---

### #3. Using [`transcode(_:from:to:stoppingOnError:into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2853783-transcode) function

The following example transcodes the UTF-8 representation of an initial string into Unicode scalar values (UTF-32 code units) that can be used to build a new string:

```
let string = "Café "
let bytes = Array(string.utf8)

var newString = ""
_ = transcode(bytes.makeIterator(), from: UTF8.self, to: UTF32.self, stoppingOnError: true, into: {
    newString.append(String(Unicode.Scalar($0)!))
})
print(newString) // prints: Café
```

---

### #4. Using `Array`'s [`withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994771-withunsafebufferpointer) method and `String`'s [`init(cString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init) initializer

`init(cString:)` has the following declaration:

```
init(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>)
```

> Creates a new string by copying the null-terminated UTF-8 data referenced by the given pointer.

The following example shows how to use `init(cString:)` with a pointer to the content of a `CChar` array (i.e. a well-formed UTF-8 code unit sequence) in order to create a string from it:

```
let bytes: [CChar] = [67, 97, 102, -61, -87, 32, -16, -97, -121, -85, -16, -97, -121, -73, 0]

let newString = bytes.withUnsafeBufferPointer({ (bufferPointer: UnsafeBufferPointer<CChar>)in
    return String(cString: bufferPointer.baseAddress!)
})
print(newString) // prints: Café
```

---

### #5. Using `Unicode.UTF8`'s [`decode(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/utf8/2907346-decode) method

To decode a code unit sequence, call `decode(_:)` repeatedly until it returns `UnicodeDecodingResult.emptyInput`:

```
let string = "Café "
let codeUnits = Array(string.utf8)

var codeUnitIterator = codeUnits.makeIterator()
var utf8Decoder = Unicode.UTF8()
var newString = ""

Decode: while true {
    switch utf8Decoder.decode(&codeUnitIterator) {
    case .scalarValue(let value):
        newString.append(Character(Unicode.Scalar(value)))
    case .emptyInput:
        break Decode
    case .error:
        print("Decoding error")
        break Decode
    }
}

print(newString) // prints: Café
```

---

### #6. Using `String`'s [`init(bytes:encoding:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126734-init) initializer

Foundation gives `String` a `init(bytes:encoding:)` initializer that you can use as indicated in the Playground sample code below:

```
import Foundation

let string = "Café "
let bytes: [Unicode.UTF8.CodeUnit] = Array(string.utf8)

let newString = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(String(describing: newString)) // prints: Optional("Café ")
```

Comment: #2 above is the general simple safe and efficient answer.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible to convert UTF8 code points to a Swift String idiomatically using the `UTF8` Swift class. Although it's much easier to convert from String to UTF8!

```
import Foundation

public class UTF8Encoding {
  public static func encode(bytes: Array<UInt8>) -> String {
    var encodedString = ""
    var decoder = UTF8()
    var generator = bytes.generate()
    var finished: Bool = false
    do {
      let decodingResult = decoder.decode(&generator)
      switch decodingResult {
      case .Result(let char):
        encodedString.append(char)
      case .EmptyInput:
        finished = true
      /* ignore errors and unexpected values */
      case .Error:
        finished = true
      default:
        finished = true
      }
    } while (!finished)
    return encodedString
  }

  public static func decode(str: String) -> Array<UInt8> {
    var decodedBytes = Array<UInt8>()
    for b in str.utf8 {
      decodedBytes.append(b)
    }
    return decodedBytes
  }
}

func testUTF8Encoding() {
  let testString = "A UTF8 String With Special Characters: "
  let decodedArray = UTF8Encoding.decode(testString)
  let encodedString = UTF8Encoding.encode(decodedArray)
  XCTAssert(encodedString == testString, "UTF8Encoding is lossless: \(encodedString) != \(testString)")
}
```

Of the other alternatives suggested:

- Using `NSString` invokes the Objective-C bridge;
- Using `UnicodeScalar` is error-prone because it converts UnicodeScalars directly to Characters, ignoring complex grapheme clusters; and
- Using `String.fromCString` is potentially unsafe as it uses pointers.

Comment: Thank you for decoding UTF8 encoding! You can remove `import Foundation` from the top, that's the whole reason I want to use this..

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful.  Here is a link to the Sandbox with this working with a couple updates and made decode a bit easier.  http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/2dde62756a95d6d1c7bb88068cb35ebfe4b13ffc3ec891856992166caa8a291d

Comment: Your use of the words "encode" and "decode" are the opposite of how I think about the conversions between strings and UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 5):

improve on Martin R's answer

```
import AppKit

let utf8 : CChar[] = [65, 66, 67, 0]
let str = NSString(bytes: utf8, length: utf8.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(str) // Output: ABC
```

---

```
import AppKit

let utf8 : UInt8[] = [0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC, 0]
let str = NSString(bytes: utf8, length: utf8.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(str) // Output: €
```

---

What happened is `Array` can be automatic convert to `CConstVoidPointer` which can be used to create string with `NSSString(bytes: CConstVoidPointer, length len: Int, encoding: Uint)`

Comment: Note that your code converts the 0 byte as well, to a NUL-character in the created NSString.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

`let s = String(bytes: arr, encoding: .utf8)`

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a comprehensive answer regarding string manipulation in Swift myself. Relying on cast to and from `NSString` and other unsafe pointer magic just wasn't doing it for me. Here's a safe alternative:

First, we'll want to extend `UInt8`. This is the primitive type behind `CodeUnit`.

```
extension UInt8 {
    var character: Character {
        return Character(UnicodeScalar(self))
    }
}
```

This will allow us to do something like this:

```
let codeUnits: [UInt8] = [
    72, 69, 76, 76, 79
]

let characters = codeUnits.map { $0.character }
let string     = String(characters)

// string prints "HELLO"
```

Equipped with this extension, we can now being modifying strings.

```
let string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMONP"

var modifiedCharacters = [Character]()
for (index, utf8unit) in string.utf8.enumerate() {

    // Insert a "-" every 4 characters
    if index > 0 && index % 4 == 0 {
        let separator: UInt8 = 45 // "-" in ASCII
        modifiedCharacters.append(separator.character)
    }
    modifiedCharacters.append(utf8unit.character)
}

let modifiedString = String(modifiedCharacters)

// modified string == "ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MONP"
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this will only work with ASCII character strings? I.e., it will mess things up if there are Danish letters Æ Ø Å æ ø å in the string? Or accented letters? Not to mention other alphabets like Russian cyrillic and the Greek alphabet and Chinese and ...

Comment: Yes, that assumption is correct. This solution will only work for single byte (ASCII) characters only and will quickly break on anything like emoji or international characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Swift4
var units = [UTF8.CodeUnit]()
//
// update units
//
let str = String(decoding: units, as: UTF8.self)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution (now updated for **Swift 2**):

```
let utf8 : [CChar] = [65, 66, 67, 0]
if let str = utf8.withUnsafeBufferPointer( { String.fromCString($0.baseAddress) }) {
    print(str) // Output: ABC
} else {
    print("Not a valid UTF-8 string") 
}
```

Within the closure, `$0` is a `UnsafeBufferPointer<CChar>` pointing to the array's contiguous storage. From that a Swift `String` can be created.

Alternatively, if you prefer the input as *unsigned* bytes:

```
let utf8 : [UInt8] = [0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC, 0]
if let str = utf8.withUnsafeBufferPointer( { String.fromCString(UnsafePointer($0.baseAddress)) }) {
    print(str) // Output: €
} else {
    print("Not a valid UTF-8 string")
}
```

Comment: C code written in Swift syntax... and more ugly than C (which may be a good thing so people want to avoid them)

Comment: @BryanChen: I have just tried to present a Swift-only solution that does not use Foundation and Objective-C classes...

Comment: I think the true Swift way must use `Character` and `UTF8` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, it may be not such elegant than working with 'pointers' but it does the job well, those are pretty much about a bunch of new `+=` operators for `String` like:

```
@infix func += (inout lhs: String, rhs: (unit1: UInt8)) {
    lhs += Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(rhs.unit1)))
}

@infix func += (inout lhs: String, rhs: (unit1: UInt8, unit2: UInt8)) {
    lhs += Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(rhs.unit1) << 8 | UInt32(rhs.unit2)))
}

@infix func += (inout lhs: String, rhs: (unit1: UInt8, unit2: UInt8, unit3: UInt8, unit4: UInt8)) {
    lhs += Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(rhs.unit1) << 24 | UInt32(rhs.unit2) << 16 | UInt32(rhs.unit3) << 8 | UInt32(rhs.unit4)))
}
```

*NOTE: you can extend the list of the supported operators with overriding* `+` *operator as well, defining a list of the fully commutative operators for* `String`*.*

---

and now you are able to append a `String` with a unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32) character like e.g.:

```
var string: String = "signs of the Zodiac: "
string += (0x0, 0x0, 0x26, 0x4b)
string += (38)
string += (0x26, 76)
```

Comment: Just a remark: Your code creates a String from UTF-32 input (if I understand it correctly) and mine from UTF-8 input. Reading the question again I am not 100% sure what is requested here. OP mentions both "UTF-8" and "Code point" ...

Comment: @MartinR, you are right, to be fair, I'm not sure about the real question either, the reason is just the same as you just said...

Comment: Note that the UTF-8 sequence for a Unicode code point has 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting with a raw buffer, such as from the Data object returned from a file handle (in this case, taken from a Pipe object):

```
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
var unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: data.count)

data.copyBytes(to: unsafePointer, count: data.count)

let output = String(cString: unsafePointer)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Swift 3.0 version of [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) answer

```
public class UTF8Encoding {
  public static func encode(bytes: Array<UInt8>) -> String {
    var encodedString = ""
    var decoder = UTF8()
    var generator = bytes.makeIterator()
    var finished: Bool = false
    repeat {
      let decodingResult = decoder.decode(&generator)
      switch decodingResult {
      case .scalarValue(let char):
        encodedString += "\(char)"
      case .emptyInput:
        finished = true
      case .error:
        finished = true
      }
    } while (!finished)
    return encodedString
  }
  public static func decode(str: String) -> Array<UInt8> {
    var decodedBytes = Array<UInt8>()
    for b in str.utf8 {
      decodedBytes.append(b)
    }
    return decodedBytes
  }
}
```

If you want show emoji from UTF-8 string, just user *convertEmojiCodesToString* method below. It is working properly for strings like *"U+1F52B"* (emoji) or *"U+1F1E6 U+1F1F1"* (country flag emoji)

```
class EmojiConverter {
  static func convertEmojiCodesToString(_ emojiCodesString: String) -> String {
    let emojies = emojiCodesString.components(separatedBy: " ")
    var resultString = ""
    for emoji in emojies {
      var formattedCode = emoji
      formattedCode.slice(from: 2, to: emoji.length)
      formattedCode = formattedCode.lowercased()
      if let charCode = UInt32(formattedCode, radix: 16),
        let unicode = UnicodeScalar(charCode) {
        let str = String(unicode)
        resultString += "\(str)"
      }
    }
    return resultString
  }
}
```