# Convert bytes/UInt8 array to Int in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, int, byte

How to convert a 4-bytes array into the corresponding Int?

```
let array: [UInt8] ==> let value : Int
```

Example:

#### Input:

```
\0\0\0\x0e
```

#### Output:

```
14
```

#### Some code I found on the internet that doesn't work:

```
let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: 4)
data.getBytes(&size, length: 4)
// the output to size is 184549376
```

Comment: @MartinR the output is wrong, it is a real big number

Comment: @MartinR  Thanks for replying on my other posts. But so far none of them are actually solved.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `Int` is a 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms, your input data
  has only 32-bit.
- `Int` uses a little-endian representation on all current Swift platforms,
  your input is big-endian.

That being said the following would work:

```
let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
var value : UInt32 = 0
let data = NSData(bytes: array, length: 4)
data.getBytes(&value, length: 4)
value = UInt32(bigEndian: value)

print(value) // 14
```

Or using `Data` in Swift 3:

```
let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
let data = Data(bytes: array)
let value = UInt32(bigEndian: data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })
```

With some buffer pointer magic you can avoid the intermediate
copy to an `NSData` object (Swift 2):

```
let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
var value = array.withUnsafeBufferPointer({ 
     UnsafePointer<UInt32>($0.baseAddress).memory
})
value = UInt32(bigEndian: value)

print(value) // 14
```

For a Swift 3 version of this approach, see ambientlight's answer.

Comment: @HansBrende: `NSData` still has a `getBytes` method in Swift 3, only its overlay type `Data` hasn't. I have added a `Data` version, another solution for Swift 3 was already posted by ambientlight.

Comment: @HansBrende: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023838/round-trip-swift-number-types-to-from-data for a more general treatment of conversion to Data and back.

Answer (score 17):

In Swift 3 it is now a bit more wordy:

```
let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
let bigEndianValue = array.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
         ($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 1) { $0 })
}.pointee
let value = UInt32(bigEndian: bigEndianValue)
```

Comment: How is this performance wise? Any overhead in terms of data-copying and allocations / retain cycles? I want to replace NSMutableData in my server-swift code with [UInt8]

Answer (score 13):

I think Martin's answer is better than this, but I still want to post mine. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

```
let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0E]
var value : Int = 0
for byte in array {
    value = value << 8
    value = value | Int(byte)
}
print(value) // 14
```

Comment: Than why not to accept Martin's answer? There is a tick button under the number of "upvotes". Its a tick, when you click on it, it becomes green.

Comment: Actually, your answer was very helpful for me. I was getting wrong int values with the accepted method, but yours gave me the correct result. I was probably just implementing the accepted method wrong but still...

Comment: This failed for signed number. How to modify this for Signed integer? Ex: [0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xAB]

Answer (score 10):

The problem with the accepted answer comes when you don't know the size of your bytes array (or your `Data` size)

It works well with `let array : [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0x23, 0xFF]`

But it won't work with `let array : [UInt8] = [0x23, 0xFF]`
(because it will be considered as `[0x23, 0xFF, 0, 0]`)

That's why I like the @Jerry's one, with bitwise operation.

I've made a functional version of his code snippet.

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x23, 0xFF])
let decimalValue = data.reduce(0) { v, byte in
    return v << 8 | Int(byte)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Swift 5, two things to pay attention:

- As `[UInt8]` is stored in a contiguous region of memory, there's no need to convert it to `Data`, pointer can access all bytes directly.
- `Int`'s byte order is little endian currently on all Apple platform, but this is not garanteed on other platforms.

say we want `[0, 0, 0, 0x0e]` to convert to `14`. (big-endian byte order)

```swift
let source: [UInt8] = [0, 0, 0, 0x0e]
let bigEndianUInt32 = source.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }
let value = CFByteOrderGetCurrent() == CFByteOrder(CFByteOrderLittleEndian.rawValue)
    ? UInt32(bigEndian: bigEndianUInt32)
    : bigEndianUInt32
print(value) // 14
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer to do it the old-fashioned way, here's a set of methods for getting int values from a byte array. This is intended for situations where a byte array containing various kinds of data is being processed sequentially.

```
/// Class which encapsulates a Swift byte array (an Array object with elements of type UInt8) and an
/// index into the array.
open class ByteArrayAndIndex {

   private var _byteArray : [UInt8]
   private var _arrayIndex = 0

   public init(_ byteArray : [UInt8]) {
      _byteArray = byteArray;
   }

   /// Property to provide read-only access to the current array index value.
   public var arrayIndex : Int {
      get { return _arrayIndex }
   }

   /// Property to calculate how many bytes are left in the byte array, i.e., from the index point
   /// to the end of the byte array.
   public var bytesLeft : Int {
      get { return _byteArray.count - _arrayIndex }
   }

   /// Method to get a single byte from the byte array.
   public func getUInt8() -> UInt8 {
      let returnValue = _byteArray[_arrayIndex]
      _arrayIndex += 1
      return returnValue
   }

   /// Method to get an Int16 from two bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getInt16() -> Int16 {
      return Int16(bitPattern: getUInt16())
   }

   /// Method to get a UInt16 from two bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getUInt16() -> UInt16 {
      let returnValue = UInt16(_byteArray[_arrayIndex]) |
                        UInt16(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 1]) << 8
      _arrayIndex += 2
      return returnValue
   }

   /// Method to get a UInt from three bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getUInt24() -> UInt {
      let returnValue = UInt(_byteArray[_arrayIndex]) |
                        UInt(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 1]) << 8 |
                        UInt(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 2]) << 16
      _arrayIndex += 3
      return returnValue
   }

   /// Method to get an Int32 from four bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getInt32() -> Int32 {
      return Int32(bitPattern: getUInt32())
   }

   /// Method to get a UInt32 from four bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getUInt32() -> UInt32 {
      let returnValue = UInt32(_byteArray[_arrayIndex]) |
                        UInt32(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 1]) << 8 |
                        UInt32(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 2]) << 16 |
                        UInt32(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 3]) << 24
      _arrayIndex += 4
      return returnValue
   }

   /// Method to get an Int64 from eight bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getInt64() -> Int64 {
      return Int64(bitPattern: getUInt64())
   }

   /// Method to get a UInt64 from eight bytes in the byte array (little-endian).
   public func getUInt64() -> UInt64 {
      let returnValue = UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex]) |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 1]) << 8 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 2]) << 16 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 3]) << 24 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 4]) << 32 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 5]) << 40 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 6]) << 48 |
                        UInt64(_byteArray[_arrayIndex + 7]) << 56
      _arrayIndex += 8
      return returnValue
   }
}
```

This is an extract from a larger class that includes methods for extracting strings and other kinds of data. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592206/253938

Comment: I did try to use this class but I am facing a swift compiler error while running on the Xcode 13 in the function `public func getUInt64() -> UInt64`
`The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`