# How to convert this python code to swift?

Tags: python, arrays, swift, byte, nsdata

I need your help to convert this **Python** script to **Swift**:

```
startcmd = b'0s000000000000000000'
data = NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(self.startcmd, len(self.startcmd))
```

Indeed, I wrote this but I know ... I am wrong:

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x0, 0x73, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 ]
let data = Data(bytes:bytes)
```

Comment: You should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769929/convert-bytes-uint8-array-to-int-in-swift

Comment: your code looks correct. note the the bytes keyword can be omitted `Data(bytes)`

Comment: Note that if startcmd  is a string the printable digit character `0`, ASCII value is `0x30`same as 48 not `0x0`

Comment: `let bytes: [UInt8] = [48, 115, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48]

String(data: Data(bytes), encoding: .ascii)! // "0s000000000000000000"`

Comment: @Leo Dabus : Thank you so much for you help.
Can you correct me. 1) I need to explod the string to get a array? 2) I need to loop the array and convert character to ASCII value?

Thank you so much for your help. ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835242/whats-the-simplest-way-to-convert-from-a-single-character-string-to-an-ascii-va/29835826?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.3419#29835826