# How to convert a byte to a String in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, byte

After searching for a while, I can't figure out how to get this simple result:

```
let byte : UInt8 = 0xF3 //Should become "F3"
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29644387/6114088/) method that won't compile when passing-in either a byte or a byte array.

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39772685/4228969

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert UInt8 byte array to string in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643986/how-to-convert-uint8-byte-array-to-string-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift native functions to have numbers as hex strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings).

Comment: This might also help: [How to convert Data to hex string in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075043/how-to-convert-data-to-hex-string-in-swift).

Comment: @toddg this didn't work for me, but this response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36286365/6114088) did the job thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

```
let s1 = String(byte, radix: 16, uppercase: true) // does not do 0-padding but works with
                                                  // all radices between 2 and 36

let s2 = String(format: "%02X", byte)             // very similar to C
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I can't believe such a response did not exist yet!