# UInt8 array not getting converted into byte string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function like this in android project

```
override fun send(data: ByteArray?) {

    if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
      warn { "Empty Request" }
      return
    }

    webSocket?.send(ByteString.of(ByteBuffer.wrap(data)))
  }
```

I have written the equivalent code in swift as

```
func send(data: [UInt8]?) {
        if(data == nil || data?.count == 0) { return }
        var dataString = String(data: Data(bytes: data!, count: data!.count), encoding : String.Encoding.utf8)!
        if(self.webSocket != nil) {
            self.webSocket!.send(text: dataString)
        }
    }
```

But I found that my code in swift is breaking when any element of UInt8 array is above 127 ie. anything between 128-255. So how will I achieve the equivalent of Java code in swift.

Comment: Use can use UInt64

Comment: What is the error that your are getting  ?

Comment: Error is Optional Value is found to be nil @humblePilgrim

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary how will that help? I am having issue in converting that UInt8 array not with the array itself.

Comment: Are you sure your data is encoded in UTF8? Can you show some samples of the bytes?

Comment: Someone here said anything above 127 is not utf8. and some of my value in array is above 127

Comment: Use `.ascii` encoding. What I find suspicious is that you even have to convert byte data to a string to send them over a socket.

Comment: Maybe sending the raw bytes instead of a string would help. String creation from raw bytes can fail, and anyway at the end of the day only raw bytes flow through sockets.

Comment: What is called `ByteString` in `Java`/`JVM` is `Data` in `Swift`/`Cocoa`. You don't need to do anything with `String`, just send `Data`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to convert \[UInt8\] to String. Error: EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340302/unable-to-convert-uint8-to-string-error-exc-bad-access)

Answer (score -2):

I tried using NSString and was able to get a valid string with array elements >127.

Here is my playground code.

```
import UIKit

var data = [UInt8]()

data.append(0)
data.append(120)
data.append(254)

print(UInt8.max)

print(data)

var dataString =  NSString(bytes: data, length: data.count, encoding: 0)
print(dataString as Any)
```

Not sure if this is a correct encoded string and will probably cause issues at the other end.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted please explain the reason too ? so that I too can learn ?